# How to create a simple wrapping Cocoa app?

Tags: macos, cocoa

## Help creating the following Cocoa app

- Generic.app

  - Contents
  - MacOS

    - Generic
    - example
  - info.plist

I want info.plist to contain an additional pair:

```
<key>CommandToExecute</key>
<string>example</string>
```

When the program is simply openedm it should call the example from the MacOS as working dir. When the program is opened via a File, it should call the example with the File path as argument.

## Edit

The answerer and [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptableCocoaApplications/SApps_handle_AEs/SAppsHandleAEs.html) link helped me to solve my task:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily access the values for custom keys in your `Info.plist`:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CommandToExecute"];
```

Once you have that value, [`NSTask`](https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTask_Class/index.html) gives
you an easy way to execute a command or script.